# Multiple section open in jQuery accordion with themes/smoothness

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to achieve j query accordion from 
    [jsfiddle.net/soboaz/3gHrv](http://jsfiddle.net/soboaz/3gHrv)
with multiple section on.

Multiple section are not opening after i added jquery css:

```
themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
```

I think classes got changed . Please help.

Comment: hi @vikram please check console errors it will help

Comment: Thanks dude,  There was some cache problem.. It got resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i created a new snippet for you.

this problem occurs may be you have not added JQuery,JQuery-ui library properly.
use this code. use this code as new HTML file.

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
    ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
    amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
    odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
    purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
    velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
    suscipit faucibus urna.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
    Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
    ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis
    lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item one</li>
      <li>List item two</li>
      <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 4</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
    et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
    faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia
    mauris vel est.
    </p>
    <p>
    Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.
    Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
    inceptos himenaeos.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<script>

  $(document).ready( function() {
    $('#accordion').accordion({
        collapsible:true,
        beforeActivate: function(event, ui) {
             // The accordion believes a panel is being opened
            if (ui.newHeader[0]) {
                var currHeader  = ui.newHeader;
                var currContent = currHeader.next('.ui-accordion-content');
             // The accordion believes a panel is being closed
            } else {
                var currHeader  = ui.oldHeader;
                var currContent = currHeader.next('.ui-accordion-content');
            }
             // Since we've changed the default behavior, this detects the actual status
            var isPanelSelected = currHeader.attr('aria-selected') == 'true';
            
             // Toggle the panel's header
            currHeader.toggleClass('ui-corner-all',isPanelSelected).toggleClass('accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-corner-top',!isPanelSelected).attr('aria-selected',((!isPanelSelected).toString()));
            
            // Toggle the panel's icon
            currHeader.children('.ui-icon').toggleClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-e',isPanelSelected).toggleClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-s',!isPanelSelected);
            
             // Toggle the panel's content
            currContent.toggleClass('accordion-content-active',!isPanelSelected)    
            if (isPanelSelected) { currContent.slideUp(); }  else { currContent.slideDown(); }

            return false; // Cancels the default action
        }
    });
});

</script>
```